# How can change the requestAnimationFrame() function to use a Promise?

Tags: javascript, animation, promise

The MDN help page on using requestAnimationFrame for simple animation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) gives an example that simply displays the animation. I want to run my animation asynchronously using a Promise, so I can use `.next(NextFunction)` to do something else when the animation is done. I've tried using the standard advice for constructing Promises and it doesn't work because requestAnimationFrame and its callback function take only one argument each, so I can't see a way to send local variables to the animation callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the heart of the code to do this. A CodePen showing a complete example is at https://codepen.io/david263/pen/MLarQp .

```
// Wrap entire animation in a Promise
function Animate(AnimStep)
    {
    var o={}; // Local Promise variables
    o.Step=AnimStep.bind(o); // Make o.Step() have this==o
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject)
        {
        // Remember some local variables
        o.resolve=resolve;
        o.start=0;
        o.id=W.requestAnimationFrame(o.Step);
        });
    } // Animate

// Define animation step
function AnimStep(timestamp)
    {
    // Fastest MsecPerFrame with lots of animation is 10 msec (60 fps)
    // Note that css transform is done without smoothing
    var MsecPerFrame=10, MsecPerAnim=2000;
    if (!this.start)
        this.start=timestamp;
    var progress = timestamp - this.start;
    GreenBarEl.style.left=progress / MsecPerFrame + 'px';
    if (progress < MsecPerAnim)
        W.requestAnimationFrame(this.Step);
    else
        this.resolve();
    } // AnimStep

// Run the animation and signal when done
Animate(AnimStep).then(Done);
```

Comment: The CodePen also includes code to interrupt the animation before it is complete by resolving the Promise (Promises themselves do not support interrupting).